# urllib2.urlopen error on Box API - can't convert to proper string

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, box-api, box-view-api

I am trying to send a POST to the Box API but am having trouble with sending it through Python. It works perfectly if I use curl:

```
curl https://view-api.box.com/1/sessions \
-H "Authorization: Token YOUR_API_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"document_id": "THE_DOCUMENT_ID", "duration": 60}' \
-X POST
```

But with my python code I get a `HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST`

```
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Token '+view_api_key, 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
session_data = {"document_id" : doc_id, "duration": 60}
session_data = urllib.urlencode(session_data)
session_request = urllib2.Request("https://view-api.box.com/1/sessions", session_data, headers)
session_response = urllib2.urlopen(session_request)
```

The problem lies in my `session_data`. It needs to be a buffer in the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format (http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), so I do a `urlencode`, however the output is `'duration=60&document_id=MY_API_KEY'`, which does not preserve { } format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the View API (and the Content API), the body data, `session_data` in your code, needs to be encoded as [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

All you need to do is import the json module at the beginning of your code (i.e. `import json`) and then change

```
session_data = urllib.urlencode(session_data)
```

to

```
session_data = json.dumps(session_data)
```

dumps() converts the python dict into a JSON string.

(as a sidenote, I would *highly* recommend not using urllib and using the [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library instead.)

Comment: Up-voting for mentioning Requests

Comment: Thanks seanrose. Can you let me know why requests is preferred over urllib?

Comment: @DjangoNovice, it's 1000% easier to use, is way more intuitive, and the functions map more closely to HTTP e.g. if I want to do a GET request to Google, I do requests.get('http://www.google.com'). The vast majority of the Python community also uses Requests now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [python-boxview](https://github.com/caxap/python-boxview). It's tiny python library for BoxView.

```py
   from boxview import boxview

   api = boxview.BoxView('YOUR_API_KEY')
   ses = api.create_session('DOCUMENT_ID', duration=90)
```